# Inverse Fourier transform not evaluating

Tags: fourier-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries

I'm trying to do this simple task:

```
InverseFourierTransform[0.031622*Exp[0.4995 ω^2], ω, t]
```

*Mathematica* 9.0 can't handle it for some reason (it returns with the same code), yet Wolfram|Alpha spits out a decent result.

What am I doing wrong? It seems I am making a very simple mistake somehow.

Comment: Can you show us the results you get from WA ?

Comment: It seems after trying again, WA doesn't solve it either. I misinterpreted its result.
Is it at all possible to do this calculation?

Comment: `InverseFourierTransform[a Exp[-b v^2], v, w]`

Comment: Thanks.

Seems like positive exponentials are the source of the problem.

Comment: It's simply because the `InverseFourierTransform` of your expression doesn't exist. Try `InverseFourierTransform[Exp[ -b v^2], v, w, 
   Assumptions -> #] & /@ {b > 0, b < 0}`

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a square-integrable function, so the FT might be tricky to define even by hand, since the function blows up as $|\omega|\to\infty$. For example, note that `InverseFourierTransform[Exp[a w^2], w, t, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]` generates `ConditionalExpression[E^(t^2/(4 a))/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-a]), Re[a] < 0]`. That isn't to say it's impossible, as even non-square-integrable functions like $\omega^2$ can be FT'ed, but it's tricky.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
I should have invested more time into the underlying maths than trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus In contrast to `w^2`, this function blows up too hard to have an IFT (it cannot be suitably regularized).